# How to get current branch name with nodegit?

Tags: javascript, nodegit

I need to know which branch is currently checked out.

One solution I see is to list branches and check which one '===' current 'HEAD'. Is there another way ?

Answer (score 4):

Use this code:

```
import * as Git from 'nodegit';

let repo: Git.Repository = await Git.Repository.open("path to the repo");

let currentBranch: Git.Reference = await repo.getCurrentBranch();

let currentBranchName: string = currentBranch.shorthand();
```